# Zend Paginate - find a specific record within the result

Tags: zend-framework

I appreciate that this may not be possible, but is there a way to make Zend Paginate go to a specific item (record)?

The result I would like would allow me to seek a specific record in a tabled list of results, and display the appropriate page (within all available pages) combined with a name anchor tag to display the specific record.

To clarify: If I had the results as a Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract I would use the seek() method in a similar fashion to $rowset->seek(8); Although I don't believe the result returned by the DbSelect adapter is a SeekableIterator?

The code within my Mapper (using the Table Data Gateway pattern):

```
public function paginate($where = array(), $order = null)
{

    $select = $this->getDbTable()->select()->from($this->getTableName(), $this->getTableFields());

    foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
            $select->where($key, $value);
    }

    $select->order($order);

    $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select);
    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);

    return $paginator;
}
```

Within my controller:

```
    $cache_id = sha1('list');
    $mapper = new Application_Model_Galleries_Mapper();

    if(!($data = Zend_Registry::get('cache')->load($cache_id))) {

        $data = $mapper->paginate(array(), $sort);
        Zend_Registry::get('cache')->save($data, $cache_id, array('list'), 7200);
    }

    $data->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page'));
    $data->setItemCountPerPage(30);

    $this->view->paginator = $data;
```

Comment: for starters `...Adapter_DbSelect()` returns an array, you might see if your code will work with `...Adapter_DbTableSelect()` as it returns a rowset object. Reference [Zend_Pagainator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html)

Comment: That works thanks! If you want to put that as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a `Zend_Paginator` with a seekable iterator (Zend_Db_Table_Rowset) use the `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect()` as it returns a rowset object, as opposed to `Zend_Paginator_Adaoter_DbSelect()` which returns an array().

[Zend_Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html)